# Updating Date_n in jdbc using to-date function

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I want to update date_n in database using to date function but it always gives me an error 'unclosed character literal '.

```
 try {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String radio = "";
    String date = f.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
    if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
        radio ="Masculin";
    }else{
        if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
            radio ="Féminin"; 
        }
    }
    requete =" update humain set nom = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"',prenom='"+jTextField3.getText()+"',adresse ='"+jTextField4.getText()+"',date_n="'to_date('"+date+"','yyyy-mm-dd')"+"',sex = '"+radio+"'where id= '"+jTextField1.getText()+"'";
    state.executeUpdate(requete);
    RefreshTable();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(easy_methodes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the `sql` string concatenation errors and cross site scripting issues (look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)), you need to use the `preparedstatement.setString()` and `setDate()` etc.. as shown below:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser1.getDate().getTime());

requete = "update humain set nom = ?, prenom=?, adresse=?, date_n=?, sex=? where id=?";
state = con.prepareStatement(requete);
updateSales.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
updateSales.setString(2, jTextField3.getText());
updateSales.setString(3, jTextField4.getText());
updateSales.setDate(4, sqlDate);
updateSales.setString(5, radio);
updateSales.setString(6, jTextField1.getText());
state.executeUpdate(requete);
```

Comment: I used in date a Jdatechooser wich i add the format ("yyyy-MM-dd") like this               jDateChooser1.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: updated answer to get sqldate from jDateChooser1.getDate()